# Converting las data into xyz with QGIS

Tags: qgis, las

I want to use QGIS 3.4.13 to convert las files into xyz-text files.

So far I installed the LAStools Toolbox in QGIS and I think I can use the las2txt tool for the conversion. However I get the error message

> The system cannot find the path specified

According to [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307116/lastools-plugin-in-qgis-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified) I'm supposed to download the LAStools Software from [here](https://rapidlasso.com/LAStools/). However, the software requires to pay a licence fee ([pricing](https://rapidlasso.com/pricing/)), but I am looking for a cost free solution.

In this [chat](https://community.esri.com/thread/91620) a user said:

> > I would suggest using an open source tool.   LASTools is a great open source tool for handling and converting LAS files.
>
> You would need to use the LAS2TXT function and you could get an ascii
> text file of the lidar data.

Thus, this particular tool is for free after all? But then why do I get the error message?

Perhabs there is an alternative to LAStools to convert las data into xyz?

Comment: If you are not restricted to use QGIS, I would recommend SAGA GIS for this task. There you can import LAS files, create subsets and export point clouds to xyz files.

Comment: Give a look to this question. It is a bit older but i think that discuss the same problem in LAStools,  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191590/qgis-2-14-1-lastools-install-error-wrong-value-for-parameter-msys-folder

Comment: If you read the LICENSE.txt you could find "There are TWO parts to LAStools. One part is OPEN source (LGPL 2.1). The other part is CLOSED source and requires licensing for most commercial or government use. " LAS2TXT is  "free" open-source LGPL

Comment: The answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307213/36393 is a good one, **did you change the LASTool folder?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default folder for LASTool is `C:\LASTools`.

You need to change the actual destination manually.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is only part of the answer; you first need to download the actual software (as specified here: gis.stackexchange.com/a/307213/36393) on top of the plugin. Then the location of the downloaded software should indeed be specified as illustrated here.